# Can "it's" be omitted in the following case?

Tags: grammar, informal-language, colloquial-language

> She wriggles herself closer to me. (It's) Definitely not my imagination
>   playing a prank on me.

I wonder if you can omit "it's" in situations like these (at least in informal writing).

I checked Google Books and found only [one](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=_RnWqxABCcQC&q=%22Definitely%20not%20my%20imagination%22&dq=%22Definitely%20not%20my%20imagination%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQqfikocfdAhVR6LwKHQ5vDbcQ6AEITTAH) instance of this usage. But I still have some doubts. That's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do so in writing that reflects the thought of a character in a narrative, and in other quasi-conversational contexts. Such ellipsis is idiomatic.

P.S. Your Google search is fatally flawed because it's far too specific to yield meaningful results. Definitely not a good idea to use Google for this sort of question.

Comment: And something like "But a lot of fun talk about prison today" ([Prison Mike - The Office US](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7RoP1LKMeM)) is idiomatic too?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence fragments are ubiquitous in spoken English, where tone of voice, gestures, and body language help convey meaning and where the opportunity to ask questions prevents much mis-communication.

And sentence fragments are frequent in written English, particularly informal English. But an English reader expects a subject and a verb. When both are missing, it requires an extra effort by the reader to parse the fragment. So I view it as a discourtesy to me the reader if the writer is too lazy to write "It's."

Now if you are reporting speech, then of course you will write in sentence fragments to be realistic. But otherwise it seems that omitting "It's" subtracts rather than adds to the clarity of your prose.